# Writing lists to a file with some custom formatting

Tags: python, file, list, python-2.7, save

I'm having some issues saving my lists to a file, the two ways in which I have tried have both yielded the undesired output.

The first way I tried was:

```
savefile.write(str(full_list))
```

returns:

```
[u'Smith', u'Malte Low', u'Day', u'George']
```

The other way I tried was:

```
for fitem in full_list:
    file.write(str(fitem))
```

returns:

```
SmithMalte LowDayGeorge
```

I am ideally looking for it to return:

```
Smith, Malte, Low, Day, George
```

I'm not quite sure how to use `.join` to make this work but it seems like the best option, I may be wrong.

Anyone got any ideas how I should be fixing this, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance
- Hy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use.

```
 ", ".join(full_list)
```

And then write the results to the file.

See the snippet -

```
>>> full_list = [u'Smith', u'Malte Low', u'Day', u'George']
>>> print ", ".join(full_list)
Smith, Malte Low, Day, George
```

**EDIT** - Just saw that you wanted a comma between `Malte Low`, then, you can just do

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> ", ".join(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, full_list)))
u'Smith, Malte, Low, Day, George'
```

Comment: Didn't know I could do that. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Given the list

```
[u'Smith', u'Malte Low', u'Day', u'George']
```

You may try

```
savefile.write(','.join(full_list))
```

But that would simply return

```
Smith,Malte Low,Day,George
```

which may not be what you wan't as your desired output, delimits words and not the items by ','

So you may want to do

- [join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with spaces
- followed by [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)ting the resultant string by spaces
- and then [join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)  back by comma

  ```
  savefile.write(','.join(' '.join(full_list).split()))
  ```

But then you have to iterate multiple times. To perform the operation on a single iteration, you can use [itertools.chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
from itertools import chain
savefile.write(','.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(e.split()
                       for e in full_list)))
```